# What is the cause of this inconsistent behaviour of TeX-command-buffer when narrowing?

Tags: latex, auctex, region, narrowing

When editing medium sized .tex files, I often find it convenient to make use of the [narrow](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html) command `C-x n n (narrow-to-region)`, usually in combination with the [mark section](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Marking-_0028LaTeX_0029.html) command `C-c * (LaTeX-mark-section)`.

I then wish to compile only the accessible portion. For this purpose, I have been using the [Tex command](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Starting-a-Command.html) `C-c C-b (TeX-command-buffer)`, but recently this command has started acting inconsistently. Depending on the position of [point](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Point.html), it sometimes

1. Compiles only the accessible portion
2. Compiles the entire buffer
3. Returns the message `ad-Advice-TeX-region-create: End of buffer`

Compiling the accessible portion is what I intend, and I can usually (but not always) trigger this behaviour by putting point at the beginning of a line or at the end of the accessible portion.

Compilation of the entire buffer seems to happen sometimes when I have previously compiled the entire buffer with `C-c C-c (TeX-command-master)`, but this is not consistent at all.

The `End of buffer` error is usually triggered by not placing point at the beginning of a line. It also seems to happen more frequently if there is a reference in the accessible portion to something in the inaccessible portion.

Sometimes (usually if I first trigger the `End of buffer` error by running `C-c C-b` with point placed mid-line, and then run `C-c C-b` with point placed at the beginning of a line) it happens that, although compilation occurs, new changes are *not* included in the output `_region_.pdf` file, although they *are* included in the `_region_.tex` file.

As a side-note, which is perhaps related, the Tex command `C-c C-z (LaTeX-command-section)` also behaves differently if I narrow: Instead of compiling the current section inside the accessible portion, it compiles only from the beginning of the section until the position of point.

I guess first narrowing and then running `C-c C-b` is not the intended use of the command `C-c C-b`. In that case, I should instead make my own command for this specific purpose. But it used to work for me consistently with the intended effect, so I am interested in knowing what might be the cause of this inconsistent behaviour.